# Tridion Interacting with the Application Monitoring Web service

Tags: 2013, c#

I need to make some windows service that will monitor Tridion health meaning that it will use Tridion Monitoring service. Inside of documentation on SDL live content there is one section explained:

*You can access the Application Monitoring Web service through, for example, the SOAP protocol. The Web service exposes a TridionMonitoringAgent interface with a GetStatus() method that returns an array of ServiceStatus elements.*

And than there is an example of XML response to a SOAP request

```
<ServiceStatus>
  <ServiceType>Content Manager Publisher</ServiceType>
  <ProcessId>2364</ProcessId>
  <Status>NotResponding</Status>
  <StatusChangeTime>2006-10-17T13:12:02Z</StatusChangeTime>
  <LastReportTime>2006-10-17T14:46:02Z</LastReportTime>
  <MonitoredThreadCount>15</MonitoredThreadCount>
  <NonRespondingThreads>
    <ThreadStatus>
      <ThreadId>13</ThreadId>
      <ThreadName>The name of the thread</ThreadName>
      <StatusChangeTime>2006-10-17T13:12:02Z</StatusChangeTime>
      <LastReportTime>2006-10-17T14:46:02Z</LastReportTime>
    </ThreadStatus>
  </NonRespondingThreads>
</ServiceStatus>
<ServiceStatus>
  <ServiceType>Workflow Agent</ServiceType>
  <ProcessId>2464</ProcessId>
  <Status>NotResponding</Status>
  <StatusChangeTime>2006-10-17T14:31:02Z</StatusChangeTime>
  <LastReportTime>2006-10-17T14:47:02Z</LastReportTime>
  <MonitoredThreadCount>2</MonitoredThreadCount>
</ServiceStatus>
```

I am not sure how to get connection to Tridion Monitoring Service and how to get request/response like this. Can someone share some code or example?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Monitoring Agent Web service, you need to install it as a .NET Web service or as a Java Web Service. The windows service will only expose this over log file or catching SNMP traps

- Installing the Monitoring Agent Web service as a .NET Web application:

  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-98F4F2C1-3B39-4B9E-A99E-31DBB8342A53
- Installing the Monitoring Agent Web service as a Java Web application:

  http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202013%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-283C1B49-8918-4143-95E6-FBAC82FFF632

From there you should be able to connect to the webservice endpoint and consume it as usual